# All subscribers as a target DE for SQL Query activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

With the help of script activity shared by Eliot [here](https://mc.chat/updating-auto-suppression-lists/), similarly I am trying to update the target DE as **All Subscribers** in a SQL query activity.

Here is the updated code I am using in the script, but for some reason it is not working for me.
Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load('Core', '1');
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var queryStr = '';
queryStr += 'SELECT DISTINCT';
queryStr += '\nsub.SubscriberKey AS [Subscriber Key]';
queryStr += '\nsub.EmailAddress AS [Email Address]';
queryStr += '\nFROM _Sent s';
queryStr += '\nLEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub'; 
queryStr += '\n   ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey';
queryStr += '\nLEFT JOIN _Open o';
queryStr += '\n   ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey';
queryStr += '\nWHERE o.SubscriberKey IS NULL';
var queryDef = {
CustomerKey: 'QUERY_ACTIVITY_EXTERNAL_KEY', //Replaced with the SQL query activity external key
ObjectID: 'QUERY_ACTIVITY_URL_ID', //Replaced with the SQL query activity URL ID
QueryText: queryStr,
TargetType: 'DE',
TargetUpdateType: 'Update',
DataExtensionTarget: {
  CustomerKey: 'All Subscribers - xxxx', //Replaced with the All Subscribers External Key
  Name: 'All Subscribers'
}
};
var updateQuery = prox.updateItem('QueryDefinition', queryDef);
Write('result: ' + Stringify(updateQuery))
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: with your code, are you trying to update the table "all subscribers", or are you trying to update a query activity that updates the table for you? Your code sample updates a query activity, not the table. (in that, it assumes that the query activity already exists)

Comment: @JonasLamberty you are correct there, Using the script I am trying to replace the current DE "Allsub_Test" with the [All subscribers] DE as my SQL query target DE. However, it seems like the script is not doing it so.

I have attached a screenshot for the reference.

Comment: aha, you are trying to target All Subscribers with an SQL Query. That is not possible. All Subscribers is not a DE and cannot be targeted via SQL. You have to export your source DE to Safehouse and import to All Subscribers.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks, @JonasLamberty! Just another quick question: using the above script, I am able to replace the target Data Extension as Auto-suppression list (similarly to what Eliot has done in this video https://mc.chat/updating-auto-suppression-lists/). So, why can't we do it for All Subscribers too?
is it because in the backend Auto-suppression list is a DE and All Subscribers is not?

Comment: Autosuppression configurations are DEs. All Subscribers List is not. Try retrieving all DEs via API, and you will be able to verify this.

Comment: see also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366834/can-auto-suppression-configurations-be-targeted-via-sql-query-activity

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation @JonasLamberty, it makes complete sense now.

Comment: Nice. Then, lets close this ;) I will summarize into an answer

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to target All Subscribers with an SQL Query. That is not possible. All Subscribers is not a DE and cannot be targeted via SQL. You have to export your source DE to Safehouse and import to All Subscribers.

While Autosuppression configurations are DEs,  All Subscribers List is not. Try retrieving all DEs via API, and you will be able to verify this.
[Can Auto-Suppression Configurations be targeted via SQL Query activity?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366834/can-auto-suppression-configurations-be-targeted-via-sql-query-activity)